# Annotate the distance on nodes of a dendrograms

Tags: r, dendextend

Consider a simple dendrogram like

```
dend <- 1:5 %>% dist %>% hclust %>% as.dendrogram
```

How can I annotate the distance (height) on the nodes? I looked up the `dendextend` package but it does not offer such a feature. However, I know I can the list of these distances from

```
heights <- as.list(dend %>% get_nodes_attr("height"))
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: To annotate the nodes, you could use `with(pvclust:::hc2axes(as.hclust(dend)), text(x.axis, y.axis, y.axis, pos = 1))
`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example using `hc2axes` from the `pvclust` package:

```
# install.packages("pvclust") # install package if needed
plot(hc <- hclust(dist( mtcars[1:10, ])))
with(pvclust:::hc2axes(hc), 
     text(x.axis, y.axis, round(y.axis, 2), adj = c(.5, 1))
)
```

[image]

Comment: How can I annotate the nodes with custom text or numbers not necessarily hclust distances?

Comment: @sam alter the labels argument of the `text` call.

Answer (score 1):

With the help from the comment one solution is:

```
heights <- get_nodes_attr(HC[[i]], "height")
heights <- as.list(sort(heights))
heights[which(heights ==0)] <- NULL
for (node in 1: length(heights)){
  with(pvclust:::hc2axes(as.hclust(dend)),
    text(x.axis[node], y.axis[node], pos = 1, sprintf("%.2f", heights[node]))) 
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. However, I don't think there's any need for loops and `heights` arrangements - have a look at my example.