# Compute distance between two nodes in a hclust dendrogram

Tags: r, distance, dendrogram, hclust

Is there a way to compute the distance of two nodes, defined as the height of their **lowest common ancestor**, on a hclust dendrogram?

A demo example can be referred here:
[Annotate the distance on nodes of a dendrograms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36129111/annotate-the-distance-on-nodes-of-a-dendrograms)

Answer (score 1):

A perfect solution is to use the stats::cophenetic() function.